# Android Third Party Libraries for consuming webservice

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley, android-ksoap2, loopj

I have used lot of third party libs for my projects for consuming web service. I have certain queries regarding this.

1. Is there any way of consuming web service without using third party libs? If yes, which is more efficient and less time consuming?(third party or in-built)
2. I have used libs like **loopj**, **Ksoap2** from github. Will there be any copyright issues? what about the authenticity?
3. Who develop these libs and how safe are our data's while parsing?
4. Is Volley library developed by Google? as i could see document kind of thing in android's official page [ https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html ]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there is no way we can consume web service without using third
>   party libs? If yes, which is more efficient and less time
>   consuming?(third party or inbuilt)

- You can have your own Web service using HttpUrlConnection
- Writing your own simple Web service with basic features will not take more than a couple of hours.
- Benefit of using third party lib is, they will have more feature, that we need to take care ex: caching, threading etc..

> I have used libs like loopj, Ksoap2 from GitHub. Will there be any
>   copyright issues? what about the authenticity?

- If MIT license or Apache License, Version 2.0, we can use freely. If it's GPL then you need to consider.

> Who develop these libs and how safe are our data's while parsing?

- I can say they are our friendly developers.(May be you can also develop one)

> Is Volley library developed by Google? as I could see document kind of
>   thing in Android's official page [
>   https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html ]

- Yes.

Comment: I am just concerned about the data leak issue, so if the library is certified under apache or MIT then we can use them without any worry? @Muthukrishnan